# Prefix for the rails generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, scaffolding

Is there a way to generate a scaffold with the admin folder prefix..For example I want one Admin folder and a few controllers for that admin folder. I want to do a scaffold for each controller in the admin folder and i wanted to know if there was something like

```
script/generate scaffold admin:something somefield:string
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
The scaffold generator can take a namespaced argument:

# Rails 3
rails g scaffold Admin::Something somefield:string

# Rails 2
script/generate scaffold Admin::Something somefield:string
```

Answer (score -1):

Note, that if you'd like to leave model unprefixed, you have to edit some of generated files by hand to implement it. That is why I created [rails-admin-scaffold](http://rubygems.org/gems/rails-admin-scaffold) gem and wrote detailed [article](http://dhampik.com/blog/rails-admin-scaffold) about custom admin area scaffolding. If that's already not relevant for you, maybe it'll help someone else.